# channel:entries and segment with Low Variables

Tags: channel-entries, stash, low-variables, parsing

This is my Low Variable **var="lv_article"**:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1" channel="{segment_1}"}
     <h1 class="title">{title}</h1>                   
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

When it's parsed inside Stash, the channel data is not parsed when channel="{segment_1}" is used:

```
{embed="structure/.model"}

{exp:stash:set name='main'}
   {exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
          {if segment_1 == 'science' AND segment_2 == ''}  
                  {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_article"}
          {/if}
  {/exp:ifelse} 

{/exp:stash:set}
```

I tried {exp:channel:entries limit="1" channel="{segment_1}" parse="inward"}, it doesn´t resolved the problem.
Does someone knows how to resolve this problem??

Thanks in advance,

Stéphane

Comment: Do you have early parsing turned on in your Low Variables settings?

Comment: Hi Jean, yes i did. I read again the docs, i'm using:  {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_article" preparse:segment_1="{segment_1}"}. It's working fine!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the content of your `lv_article` variable, you could just use the variable syntax instead of the tag syntax:

```
{lv_article}
```

Having early parsing enabled has no effect when using the tag syntax, only when using the above variable syntax.